# Yii2 relations with junction table

Tags: yii2, relationship, junction

I have free tables: user, book, user_book, offers

user table has method:

```
public function getBooks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(UserBook::className(), ['user_id' => 'id']);
    }
```

user_book table has two fields: user_id, book_id; and methods

```
public function getUser()
   {
        return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id']);
   }

public function getBook()
   {
        return $this->hasOne(Book::className(), ['id' => 'book_id']);
   }
```

table offer have method like: getUser(), getBook(),

and now I would like show Books which user don't have. I try do something like

```
     $query = Offer::find()
                ->with('user')
                ->andWhere([
                    'offer.status' => Offer::STATUS_ACTIVE,
                ]);

$query->andWhere(['not in', 'offer.book_id', 'user.books.book_id']);
```

but it doesn't work. Do you have some ideas how can I make it?

Answer (score 1):

[Yii2 docs, relation via junction table](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#junction-table)

> In database modelling, when the multiplicity between two related
>   tables is many-to-many, a junction table is usually introduced. For
>   example, the order table and the item table may be related via a
>   junction table named order_item. One order will then correspond to
>   multiple order items, while one product item will also correspond to
>   multiple order items.
>
> When declaring such relations, you would call either via() or
>   viaTable() to specify the junction table. The difference between via()
>   and viaTable() is that the former specifies the junction table in
>   terms of an existing relation name while the latter directly uses the
>   junction table. For example,

```
class Order extends ActiveRecord
{
    public function getItems()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Item::className(), ['id' => 'item_id'])
            ->viaTable('order_item', ['order_id' => 'id']);
    }
}
or alternatively,

class Order extends ActiveRecord
{
    public function getOrderItems()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(OrderItem::className(), ['order_id' => 'id']);
    }

    public function getItems()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Item::className(), ['id' => 'item_id'])
            ->via('orderItems');
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, I have    
`public function getBooks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Book::className(), ['id' => 'book_id'])
            ->viaTable('{{%UserBooks}}', ['user_id' => 'id']);
    }` but how to build query?

Comment: You could just use `via('userBooks')` - u defined this relation as i can see. In query use `->joinWith(['books'])` and then in query use it as `books.id`, not `user.books.id`